# What is "it" referring to in this sentence

Tags: pronouns

> One of them added that the diabolical shrieks and cackles of this species have earned it

"It" in this sentence is referring to what? This book is from Richard Dawkins' God Delusion. In the chapter that talks about the the personal experience's argument

> One of the cleverer and more mature of my undergraduate contemporaries, who was deeply religious, went camping in the Scottish isles. In the middle of the night he and his girlfriend were woken in their tent by the voice of the devil — Satan himself; there could be no possible doubt: the voice was in every sense diabolical. My friend would never forget this horrifying experience, and it was one of the factors that later drove him to be ordained. My youthful self was impressed by his story, and I recounted it to a gathering of zoologists relaxing in the Rose and Crown Inn, Oxford. Two of them happened to be experienced ornithologists, and they roared with laughter. “Manx shearwater!” they shouted in delighted chorus. One of them added that the diabolical shrieks and cackles of this species have earned **it**, in various parts of the world and various languages, the local nickname “Devil Bird”.

Comment: One of them added that the diabolical shrieks and cackles
of this species have earned it, in various parts of the world and
various languages, the local nickname 'Devil Bird'.

Comment: 'It' is 'this species' - but you _must_ give the complete sentence, as supplied by @SouthIndianɪŋɡlɪʃɪfaɪd.

Comment: I'd say that "it" is anaphoric to "Manx Sheerwater".

Comment: @BillJ: I'd say that "it" is anaphoric to "**this species**". Syntactically speaking, the ornithologists could have shouted *anything*, with no obvious relationship to the bird mentioned later.

Comment: If someone asked what the 'Devil Bird' was, the answer would be the Manx Sheerwater. That's the bird that has earned that nickname. Its for this reason that the more salient antecedent of "it" is Manx Sheerwater.

Comment: Your parse is incorrect. It should be: The X of this species earned it [...] the local nickname of Y. To earn a nickname. That's how to explain it.

Comment: No, it isn't. My explanation is fine. It gives the more salient antecedent of "it".

Answer (score 1):

> One of them added that the diabolical shrieks and cackles of this species have earned it, in various parts of the world and various languages, the local nickname 'Devil Bird'.

[source](https://iberianature.com/britainnature/shearwater-folklore/#:%7E:text=%27Manx%20Shearwater!,local%20nickname%20%27Devil%20Bird%27.)

*it* is **this species**.  We can also say *this species earned the local nickname 'Devil Bird' through its diabolical shrieks and cackles*.